# VHOST Basic Auth conflicts with apache server-status

Tags: apache, vhosts

I am trying to get server-status to work on a server that has an apache VHOST that's using basic auth.

In the main httpd.conf configuration file I have server-status set:

```
 <Location /server-status>
   SetHandler server-status
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1 10.10.1.246
</Location>
```

If I do a GET on the hosts' server-status I get prompted for a user name and password:

```
 [root@uszmplb apache2]# GET http://$(hostname -i)/server-status
Enter username for Restricted Area at 10.10.1.246:80:
```

If I enter a username and password I have access to I can get the server-status page from the GET command. However the problem is that this needs to be automated for monitoring. And the monitoring department can't/won't monitor this host if it is protected with a username and password.

And if I move the VHOST conf with the server-status in it I can GET the server-status page:

```
[root@hostapache2]# GET http://$(hostname -i)/server-status  | head -10
<?
    require('_config.php');
    $contactsData = simplexml_load_file(USE_CMS ? WEB_ROOT . 'wordpress/contacts' :        'data/contacts.xml');
    $downloadsData = simplexml_load_file(USE_CMS ? WEB_ROOT . 'wordpress/downloads' :      'data/downloads.xml');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Problem is I need the best of both worlds. I need to server the site that has the basic auth and I need to be able to enable server-status.

I tried to solve this by giving server-status it's own VHOST configuration in an effort to separate the server-status from the VHOST that has the basic auth like so:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName host.west.company.com
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 10.10.1.246
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I had no luck there either. It just prompts for a username and password like before.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem until I've read the Apache documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html

There you can find:

> Main host goes away
>
> If you are adding virtual hosts to an existing web server, you must
>   also create a  block for the existing host. The
>   ServerName and DocumentRoot included in this virtual host should be
>   the same as the global ServerName and DocumentRoot. List this virtual
>   host first in the configuration file so that it will act as the
>   default host.

So, if you don't make this change, you lost your default web server, for example:

```
#>httpd -S
[root@localhost]# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server virtualhost.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/virtualhost.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost virtualhost.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/virtualhost.conf:4)
Syntax OK
```

If you want get your default web server again (with all default configurations, like /server-status), you have to create a named virtual host like the documentation explain:

```
[root@localhost conf]# cat defaultserver.conf

# you can't get this directive inside the <VirtualHost> tag
ExtendedStatus On

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
   ServerName default.domain.com
   DocumentRoot "/etc/httpd/htdocs"

   # Real-time info on requests and configuration
   Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

At last, you have to include your default virtual host first in the configuration:

```
[root@localhost conf]# cat virtualhosts.conf
NameVirtualHost *:80

include conf/defaultserver.conf
include conf/virtualhost.conf
```

Restart your apache server and you can validate your configuration:

```
[root@localhost]# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server default.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/defaultserver.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost default.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/defaultserver.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost virtualhost.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/virtualhost.conf:4)
Syntax OK
```